# List of Controller Routes in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, navigation, routes

What I'm trying to do:

I create some controllers, for example:

- Home
- About
- Gallery
- Contact

Now I want to create a navigation automatically. So is there a way to programmatically fetch the list of controllers/actions to build this navigation?

I don't want to fix the navigation everytime I add a controller.

Comment: did you figure this out? I need to return an array of all controller names too

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
HomeController.action_methods.each do |action|
  url_for(:action => action)
end
```

Comment: Where do you put this? in the routes.rb?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one liner that gives you all the controllers based on your routes file. I found I had a nil value, so I added the rescue, then rejected any of those rescued empty ones.  The uniq drops any duplicates.

```
Rails.application.routes.routes.collect { |r| r.defaults[:controller] rescue '' }.reject! { |c| c.empty? }.uniq
```

Added a titlecase to make them more suitable for your navigation.

```
Rails.application.routes.routes.collect { |r| r.defaults[:controller].titlecase rescue '' }.reject! { |c| c.empty? }.uniq
```

This is one for only those in an admin namespace.

```
Rails.application.routes.routes.collect { |r| r.defaults[:controller].titlecase rescue '' }.reject { |c| c.empty? }.uniq.reject { |n| !n.include?('Admin/')  }.map { |i| i.gsub('Admin/', '') }.sort
```